# jQuery simpledialog on close open another simpledialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I'm trying to get a jQuery dialog to close open clicking cancel, and open a new one. Upon clicking CANCEL I have it set up to open the first dialog. Don't mind the actual simpledialog it's trying to open, I know it doesn't make sense for it to open that dialog... just testing at this point... and no second dialog comes up upon close of the first? Nothing happens when I hit cancel, first dialog  stays up. Using SimpleDialog2 Please help!

Comment: Can you give us your HTML as well? Even better, can you setup jsFiddle?

Comment: Sure here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ztDHc/

The link for the dialog is on the  Form entitled "Clear Stored Data" , just click broken image to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain the methodology of creating a dialog on every click, you should use  the destroy method of the plugin ( assuming it has one) instead of just closing it. Otherwise you will append a new eleemnt to the DOM each and every time and they will always be there

Staying with the creation on the fly concept, you would simply open other dialog by triggering a click on the button/element that is delegated already to open it.

Assuming you have multiple rows of these buttons you would need to use a method like addClass to track which row was clicked on so you can find the correct eleement to trigger the click on.

Another approach is make a function for each dialog with an argument to pass in something like row ID or the actual element clciked in order to process your `key` inside the dialog.

```
$(document).delegate('#simplebool', 'click', function() {
        openDialog1( this);

})

function  openDialog1( el){
   var self=el; /* use this to replace "this" in dialog confirm code */
   $('<div>').simpledialog2({......})

}
```

Now you can call dialog 1 from inside dialog 2 and from the handler it is already being opened in

Comment: Got it thanks! Hrm, I wish there was an easier way of making a ton of dialogs, isn't there a way to somehow make one dialog then call it in diff functions?

Comment: I was following your lead. Really not sure what requirments are that you need a ton of dialogs and yes you can multipurpose one dialog. I just looked and saw that this is mobile dialog... I know jQueryUI type dialogs very well but not jQM. Looks like there's a lot more you can do within the click handler than in normal web page. Likely should have taged this for mobile and get better responses